# Qué estoy haciendo mal

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de agregar a MYSQL un div que ya debería quedar guardado con la clase, la data y el texto, pero no me lo agrega, en ocaciones agrega el div pero sin la clase ni el data y tampoco el mensaje ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
<?php
include("chat_database.php");

$usuario = $_POST['user'];
$mensaje = $_POST['message'];
$fecha = $_POST['date'];


$content = "<div><span class='$usuario' data-fecha='$fecha'>$mensaje</span></div>";

$base->query("INSERT INTO $messages (user,message) VALUES ('$usuario','$content')");

?>
```

Comment: No es sano guardar -así- html en la base de datos; es mezclar presentación y persistencia. Es como dormirse con los zapatos puestos.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías revisar el registro de errores `error.log` o, mejor aún, probar la consulta directamente en PHPMyAdmin o en la consola de MySQL para ver que estás rompiendo la cadena:

```
INSERT INTO messages (user, message)
    VALUES ('nombre', '<div class='nombre'>...</div>');
```

La comilla simple que tienes en `class='` hace que se termine la cadena donde inicia el valor de la columna `message`, generando el error cuando aparece `nombre`, que MySQL tratará de interpretar como una columna o valor, pero debería haber previamente una coma u operador. Adicionalmente, como te dijo **@IGeoorge**, es probable que esté de sobra el `$` en el nombre de la tabla.

Si solo deseas "corregir" este error, aprende a escapar comillas, agregando una diagonal invertida:

```
<?php
include("chat_database.php");

$usuario = $_POST['user'];
$mensaje = $_POST['message'];
$fecha = $_POST['date'];

// Usa comillas dobles para encerrar los atributos
$content = "<div><span class=\"$usuario\" data-fecha=\"$fecha\">$mensaje</span></div>";

$base->query("INSERT INTO messages (user, message) VALUES ('$usuario', '$content')");
```

Si realmente te interesa aprender a hacer las cosas bien, deberías usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) que, aparte de ayudarte a evitar estos errores, también minimiza el riesgo de [ataques SQL](https://diego.com.es/ataques-sql-injection-en-php).

Por último, tampoco creo conveniente que uses el nombre de usuario como clase de un contenedor, supongo que se va a complicar mantener una hoja de estilos CSS conforme agregues más usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
$base->query("INSERT INTO $messages (user,message) VALUES ('$usuario','$content')");
```

me parece que se te colo un $ en en nombre de la tabla $messages => deberia ser messages no?

Comment: De hecho hasta el nombre de la variable esta mal en el código del OP ya que el tiene mensaje

Comment: @BetaM si, pero de ultima le va a grabar el record y se dara cuenta :P hay que ver si la variable $messages no viene de ese include de ahi. anda a saber!!